# Remove underline link button in Vue.js and Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, underline

I use Vue.js for frontend and i use Vuetify as framework  i use button like below:

```
<v-btn
              class="ma-2"
              outlined
              color="success"
              width="150px"
              to="/user"
          >
            <div class="font">
              Search
            </div>
          </v-btn>
```

and i don't want underline when mouseover on it
what should i do?? it's ok before i add to="/user" and
i did this and set it as class

```
.font{
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

but don't work

and don't want use it as class

```
display: inline-block;text-decoration:none;
```

Comment: Can you make a fiddle of your issue? AFAIK `v-btn`'s should not be underlining your text by default

Comment: @maxshty thanks but i realy realy accidently find a solution after many search should set it as style  style="text-decoration: none; color: inherit;"

Answer (score 2):

I you want to remove underlining on all your links just write this in your main css file:

```
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

If you want to remove it only for a set of buttons, then create a class for those buttons e.g. `btn-link`. Then you can make it like this:

```
.btn-link a{
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

New in Vuetify v2.3.0+

"Remove text decoration with the .text-decoration-none class"

```
<a class="text-decoration-none">Non-underlined link</a>
```

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/text-and-typography/#decoration

Answer (score 0):

use it

```
<v-btn
              class="ma-2"
              outlined
              color="success"
              to="/user"
              style="text-decoration: none; color: inherit;"
          >
            <div class="font-button-search">
              جست و جو
            </div>
          </v-btn>
```